# Tags "performance" e "desempenho" poderiam ser mescladas

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, tags

Acho que as tags [performance](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance) e [desempenho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/desempenho) poderiam ser mescladas. O que acham?

Comment: Eu particularmente nunca gostei da palavra "performance", pois é neologismo. Tem meu apoio para que "performance" se torne sinônimo de "desempenho".

Comment: +1 Também concordo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defini [performance](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance) como sinônima de [desempenho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/desempenho), conforme sugestão do Math no comentário acima. Não sou contra estrangeirismos em qualquer situação, neste caso acho que os dois termos são igualmente válidos.